# Passing DataContext to a UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, datacontext

I have a page that contains a dataset:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyDefinedDataContext mydatacont = new MyDefinedDataContext();
}
```

I'd like to pass this datacontext through to a `UserControl`:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site2.Master" Inherits="WebApplication3._Default" %>
<%@ Register src="inc/Tabular.ascx" tagname="Tabular" tagprefix="testing" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <testing:Tabular ID="tabularArticles" runat="server" currentPage="3" title="Articles"/>
</asp:Content>
```

How can I do this? Would I do it in the `UserControl`'s `Page_Load` somehow?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myCtx = mydatacont;
    this.setPreInfo();
    this.getTableInfo();
    this.setTableMeta();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass it to your `UserControl`.  `DataContext` objects are inexpensive to create, so if you need access to the object there you can just instantiate a new one.

However, to answer your question directly, you can share an `HttpContext`-scoped `DataContext` among all user controls by storing it in `HttpContext.Items` such as

```
  HttpContext.Items["DataContextKey"] = new MyDataContext();
```

Then, you can initialize a field in your constructor like from your controls via

```
  _dataContext = (MyDataContext)Context.Items["DataContextKey"];
```

A more elegant implementation of this approach (and other approaches) for managing the `DataContext` life cycle in general is available at http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/246222.aspx , in a `DataContextFactory` class.

The method that will be most interesting to you is:

```
static object GetWebRequestScopedDataContextInternal(Type type, string key, string connectionString)                                   
{
    object context;

    if (HttpContext.Current == null)
    {
        if (connectionString == null)
            context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        else
            context = Activator.CreateInstance(type, connectionString);

        return context;
    }

    // *** Create a unique Key for the Web Request/Context 
    if (key == null)
        key = "__WRSCDC_" + HttpContext.Current.GetHashCode().ToString("x") + Thread.CurrentContext.ContextID.ToString();

    context = HttpContext.Current.Items[key];
    if (context == null)
    {
        if (connectionString == null)
            context = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        else
            context = Activator.CreateInstance(type, connectionString);

        if (context != null)
            HttpContext.Current.Items[key] = context;
    }

    return context;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably put a public property on your user control and set that from your parent page.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I can't figure out how to get a 'DataContext' type into my user control. I've imported the System.Data and System.Linq namespaces, but I get an error at the line: `public DataContext myCtx = new DataContext();`

Comment: Have you tried using 'MyDefinedDataContext'?  I'm assuming that's an implementation of DataContext.

Comment: Forgive me if this is lame, I'm exceptionally new to this:

When I type in 'DataContext' into Visual Studio, to doesn't highlight as a known variable type.

Answer (score 0):

Define an interface:

```
public interface IDataContextPage
{
     MyDefinedDataContext DataContext { get; }
}
```

Have the page implement this interface, and do:

```
public class MyPage: Page, IDataContextPage
{
     public MyDefinedDataContext DataContext { get { return _context; } }
}
```

Your user control can refer to this page through the interface.  Do this in the UC:

```
protected void Page_Load(..)
{
    var uc = ((IDataContextPage)this.Page).DataContext;
}
```

I would recommend creating the context in the init event in the page, not the load.

HTH.